# AAB файл убирает языковые пакеты

Tags: java, android

При тестировании приложения в Android Studio устанавливается обычный APK файл, где все ресурсы локализации есть и переключение языков работает корректно. Но когда моё приложение появилось в Play Market, то из-за новой системы от Google с AAB файлами убираются лишние языковые пакеты.

У меня возник вопрос, что мне делать, т. к. в моём приложении есть переключатель языков, который работает с помощью такого кода:

```
private static void changeLanguage(Context context, String locale) {
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale(locale);
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("language", locale);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Но из-за того, что файл AAB убирает лишние языковые пакеты, при попытке смены языка приложение вылетает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня была такая же проблема. Попробуйте добавить в `build.gradle` такой параметр:

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

и тогда всё должно быть раздельно по языкам. И второй вариант почему может не работать:

```
res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
```

эта штука если мне не изменяет память deprecated. Поэтому если тестируете на каком-то новом устройстве может и не заработать нормально.

Answer (score 3):

PlayCore API [поддерживает](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand#lang_resources) скачивание ресурсов другого языка по мере необходимости. Это не увеличит исходный размер приложения.

Вариант с `enableSplit = false` не самый предпочтительный, так как увеличит размер приложения.